# How to set height of a container to viewport height minus a 300px in height slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Excuse the newbie kind of question, I'm sure what I want to do is easy however I must be wording it right when looking for solutions.

Basically I want to set a section in html to the height of the viewport minus the height of the navigation bar and a small slider at the bottom.

I understand that this is something I need Javascript for?
If anyone could help that would be great.

I know I could

```
    .container {
        height: 100%;
        margin-top: -300px;
        min-width: 100%;
    }

    .slider-wrapper {
        height: 300px;
        min-width: 100%;
    }
```

But it really doesn't give the desired effect as it would cut off the top of the container. Is there some sort of Jquery maths we can do to subtract the height of .slider from the height of .container?

Sorry, as asked for in comments, heres some more markup, i've only included the container sections as they're the only ones that at the moment I need to interact with. Here's the html

```
    <section class="top-bar">
    </section>

    <section id="container">
    </section>

    <section class="slider-wrapper">
    </section>
```

So those are the three containers that make up the actual layout of the screen at the moment. so here's the css I have for the .container as it stands:

```
    #container {
        background: url(../img/cafe-background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
```

}

so I just need to minus the height of the .slider-wrapperunderneath from this container.

Comment: of course nothing easier as that. wait for answere

Comment: What's your HTML? And precisely what element(s) are you trying to style? Without context this question is very nearly nonsensical, and is difficult to answer without making guesses (which limits its use to others in future).

Comment: Ive updated the post for you

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, if stretch the container in the middle, leave its height to 100% and add `html, body{height:100%}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery:

Here a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zyrc0tbb/

```
<head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
        var indexd = parseInt($(document).height()) - parseInt($('.slider-wrapper').css('height')) + 'px';
        $('#container').css('height', indexd);
     });
 </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Just copy & paste it and if you want to know what I did, I can tell you it step for step

Comment: from what I understand of it, this looks like the solution i need, although i can't seem to get it to work. Ive made sure the class's and id's match up from the markup to your script but nothing :/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, just use calc() with viewport height units:

```css
.container {
        height: calc(100vh - 300px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css3 `calc` function no need of javascript:

```
.container {
    height: calc(100% - 300px)
    min-width: 100%;
}

.slider-wrapper {
    height: 300px;
    min-width: 100%;
};
```

If you want the make `.slider-wrapper` auto use nested section in your mark-up something like this:

```
<section id="container">
   <section class="slider-wrapper">
   </section>
</section>
```

Comment: [`calc()` *function*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc), rather than 'property' (here you're setting the `height` property with a value returned by the `calc()` function). Incidentally, it's worth noting that this solution (as currently written) requires the parent of the `.container` element to have a defined `height`.

Comment: Nice solution. But the height of ´.slide-wrapper´ have to be given and have to be static. So this won't work if the height of `.slide-wrapper` is auto.

Comment: Hmm the OP states the height of '.slide-wrapper' should or will be static!!So I think it's the exact solution OP is looking for..

Comment: at the moment it is static, however I did plan on making the .slide-wrapper auto, is there different solutions, can I have help with one for an auto .slide-wrapper? thanks for the help so far

Comment: So the condition to use calc is to know the value(s). I have a solution with jQuery. This works whether the height is auto or a certain value.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/e0tpnojf/). The #top-bar and #slide-wrapper have a preset height and have position: fixed. #container will fit in between those, because of the top and bottom values. #container also has position: fixed.

This solution will create a weird scrollbar if your content in #container is higher than #container div.

A simple fix for this is to use position: relative for the #container and add margins to the top and bottom.

Anyway you definately do not need css3 or javascript to do what you want. You will just need to read up on the position property. I m sure there is enough information about it on the internet to figure out how it works.

**Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/e0tpnojf/

**HTML**

```
<section id="top-bar">
</section>

<section id="container">
</section>

<section id="slider-wrapper">
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#top-bar{
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
#container{
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    top: 105px;
    bottom: 105px;
    position: fixed;
}
#slider-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```